# Запуск команд ОС Windows из Python: как вывод systeminfo команды запихнуть в переменную

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

Есть такой код:

```
import os  
os.system('systeminfo')
```

Выдает мне информации о системе Windows. Нужно вывод этой команды запихнуть в переменную и немного изменить. **Как это сделать?** Не могу сообразить. Какого типа будет переменная? Кортеж, массив, список? Запутался(((( 
Если делаю так:

```
line = os.system('systeminfo')
print line
```

То переменная line равна 0, т.е. в ней ничего нет. Что делаю не так?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

os.system возвращает код завершение программы, который в основном 0.
По правильному нужно делать как-то так:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p1 = Popen(["systeminfo"], stdout=PIPE)
output = p1.communicate()[0]
```

Comment: Мда... читал что лучше использовать subprocess. А где вывод команды? В этом случае команда выполняеться и завершается. Как обработать вывод?

Comment: ну, так в моем ответе строка output = p1.communicate()[0]
переменная output и содержит вывод.

Comment: можно упростить до `output = subprocess.check_output(command)`