# Запуск внешнего файла

Tags: python

Нужно проверить запущен ли внешний файл `my.exe`? Если нет, то запустить его..

Answer (score 2):

[popen же](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.html#file-object-creation)

Вот ссылочка частично по теме: [Запуск команд ОС Windows из Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/206151/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4-%D0%BE%D1%81-windows-%D0%B8%D0%B7-python)

Answer (score 0):

Вот модули которые стоит посмотреть:

psutil для поиска в процессах

subprocess для запуска